# how to put a $ in front of my value table numbers

Tags: python

I'm new to python and wondering how I can put a dollar sign in this spot? i think it might have something to do with line 31 in my code but I cannot figure it out

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flv4W.png

here is the code:

```
#constants
CITY_CLOSE_RATE = 2
CITY_DIST_RATE = 1
BNDRY_DIST = 20

#inputs
propValue = float(input('What is the cost of the property right now?'))
numYears = int(input('Value after how many years?'))
propDist = float(input('How far is the property from your city?'))

# select the right rate depending on the distance to the city
if propDist <= BNDRY_DIST:
    rate = CITY_CLOSE_RATE
else:
    rate = CITY_DIST_RATE
#calculate percantage
rate = rate / 100

#print header of the table
print(f'{"Years":>5} {"value":>15}')

# calculating property for every year. body of the table
for count in range (1, numYears +1) :
    increment = propValue * rate
    endVal = propValue + increment
    print (f'{count:>5}  {endVal :>15.2f}')
    propValue= endVal

#print final prop value after appreciation
print(f'Value of the property after {count} years: ${propValue : .2f}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be to use an earlier f-string to make `endVal` in to a string with a `$` added before.  As such the for loop becomes;

```
for count in range (1, numYears +1):
    increment = propValue * rate
    endVal = propValue + increment
    strEndVal = '$ ' + f'{endVal:,.2f}'
    print (f'{count:>5}  {strEndVal :>15}')
    propValue= endVal
```

Comment: You can also nest f strings, so you could replace only one line in the for loop with
`print (f"{count:>5}  {(f'$ {endVal:,.2f}') :>15}")`